# If-else statements in html

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a small change to this website I bought. I have the HTML code for it, and I have some knowledge of HTML but not of JavaScript or CSS. Could someone tell me the code to put in one of the scripts to make it like

```
if (on pageA)
   print this text
else
   print other text
```

I know this site frowns on asking questions like these, but I've tried finding the answer on w3 Schools first. Only it seemed like I would have to learn all the JavaScript knowledge prior to that to understand when I only need to know this small snippet of code.

Comment: We can't help - you **do** need to learn JavaScript if any answer here is to make sense and _actually_ help you with what you are doing.

Comment: what is "on pageA" supposed to refer to?

Comment: You need javascript, or a server side web application which serves this content, to do this. You should learn JS if you want to be a decent front end developer. It will serve you well. Don't be afraid. It's fun.

Comment: HTML is a markup language, not a programming language. It does not have any if statements. You will need some server side processing for that.

Comment: Any web developer must know any server-side langauge as well as JavaScript. Doesn't matter if he's front/back end developer. JS is a must.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "Page A" is "PageA.html", your HTML should be something like this...

```
<script>

if (window.location.href.indexOf("PageA") != -1)
   alert("You are on Page A")
else
   alert("You are not on Page A")

</script>
```

Javascript is a science and a profession, if you want professional results hire one. :)